# Cache miss for REQUEST dispatch

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, warnings

I'm currently using Spring boot updated version 3.2.0 and implemented the **SecurityFilterChain** after running the application I got this message:

```
2023-12-11T12:08:04.541+06:00  WARN 28000 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.h.HandlerMappingIntrospector     : Cache miss for REQUEST dispatch to '/' (previous null). Performing CorsConfiguration lookup. This is logged once only at WARN level, and every time at TRACE.
2023-12-11T12:08:04.550+06:00  WARN 28000 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.h.HandlerMappingIntrospector     : Cache miss for REQUEST dispatch to '/' (previous null). Performing MatchableHandlerMapping lookup. This is logged once only at WARN level, and every time at TRACE.
```

The **Code** of SecurityFilterChain:

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
    .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
            .requestMatchers("/", "/Signup", "/css/**", "/js/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
    .formLogin((form) -> form
            .loginPage("/Login")
            .permitAll()
            )
    .logout((logout) -> logout.permitAll())
    .formLogin((form) -> form.defaultSuccessUrl("/home", true));

    return http.build();
}
```

Any idea why I got this message. When I hit `localhost:8080` automatically goes to login page its fine but won't go to signup page when I clicked on signup button it just redirect to login page. Can you provide details working process and to resolve the problem.

[I followed the official documentation to implement SecurityFilterChain](https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just ran into this WARNING when upgrading a project's Spring Boot version.

This is a [current issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/38587) with Spring Boot 3.2.0.
It should be fixed with this [ticket](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/14128).

In the meantime we can change the logging level to error:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerMappingIntrospector=ERROR
```

Comment: I thought that the warning was the problem when I pressed signup and it automatically redirected to the login page. Why am I getting unusual behaviour? Any idea!

Comment: MvcRequestMatcher that will be used with your configuration is case sensitive, perhaps you should check if the sign-up path you are hitting is not different than the one configured.

Also you shouldn't really need two .formLogin() configurations.

Comment: Please check it out the project. 

[Project] (https://github.com/SakibvHossain/Demo-Project-for-Spring-Security)

Answer (score 1):

In Spring Boot version `3.2.0`, I have seen that configuring **Security (mainly related to CORS)** in the Spring Boot application can lead to multiple calls (around 8 to 9 times) to the *getResultFor(HttpServletRequest request)* method of the *HandlerMappingIntrospector* class.
Resulting in a **Cache miss for REQUEST dispatch** issue and impacting performance, as indicated in this [Link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/31588#issue-1987261317).

Consider upgrading your Spring Boot version to `3.2.1` to address this issue.

After the upgrade, I observed that Spring no longer calls the mentioned method (based on my testing, though I cannot confirm at a high level).